# How to create two columns RDLC report C#, my second column does not show data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I am trying to create two column report for labeling purposes, I followed instructions on the following link: blogs.wrox.com/article/creating-mailing-labels-in-sql-server-reporting-services

But the data keeps appearing on one column and not on both columns, I changed all sizes and tried tables and lists same results, it just won't populate the second column.

When I added a second field, column 2 shifted to the right, changing the the size of the report.

[image]

|Field 1 | -- |Field 1 Copy| -----> Column 2 (shifted)

I continued anyway and it shows two of the same values side by side, but in reality they are on the same column, which means I have two fields on the same column, if I hide one, the second will shift and show on the lift side, I have changed the font style to distinguish them from the attached photo.

[image]

| Customer1 | -- | Customer1 |

| Customer2 |

Answer (score 2):

The multiple column options in RDLC cause the second column to be treated like a second page and the data only flows into the second column once the first is populated. If you want to force someting to the second column try setting it to have new page before the field and list them. Or don't use the multiple column layout and just put a two column table on the report.

Comment: Spent days trying to figure this out.  Perfect!!!  So select your tablix, then in properties window Expand PageBreak and in BreakLocation set it to END.  Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check your width of report viewer, It seems from image that expr1 and expr2 having more width and also delete second expr2

Comment: Hi,Thank you for helping, I did check the sizes and they are ok, I made them smaller any way and still the same result, only one column is populated with data. Any other suggestion ? thank you.